# Static integer in a class method shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Consider the following code:

```
class my_class;

  // *** constructor
  function new(string name = "");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction

  // ** my_function
  function void my_function();
    static int my_static_int = 0;
    my_static_int++;
    $display("my_static_int = %0d", my_static_int);
  endfunction

endclass
```

In my code, Assume I have a sequence with body -

```
// ** body
task body();

  my_class my_class_A = new;
  my_class_A.my_function();

endtask
```

My issue is that if I were to call `body` twice from my test, the second time, `my_static_int` has the value 2 instead of what I expected which is 1.

Since `my_class_A` is destroyed each time body is run (I verify this using %p), shouldn't the subsequent run on a completely different object of `my_class` print a value of 1 again

Maybe my understanding is lacking here.. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` variable means there is only one copy of the variable and one initialization of that variable before time 0. Without the `static` keyword, it would have been an automatic variable that gets allocated and initialized each time your function gets called.

If you want a variable that gets initialized each time the object gets constructed, simply declare it as a class member variable.

Comment: I did go with making it a class variable, which is what I normally do (I thought I would try something different). Is this behaviour different from other OO languages? I assumed that every object of the class would have its own copy of the static variable.

Comment: SV static class variable behavior is the same as Java and C++.